# MySQL get data from the multiple table

Tags: mysql

I have an `eg_design` table which has the below columns:

[image]

and `eg_domains` table which has the below columns:

[image]

and `eg_fonts` table which has the below columns:

[image]

Now, Based on the **$domain_id** I want to get all the data from `eg_design` table, some data from the `eg_domains` table, and **font_name** column value from the `eg_fonts` table **But** in the `eg_design` table I have 2 font id exist on the **design_font** and **domain_font** column.

So,below query should give me 2 **font_name** from the `eg_fonts` table as on the `eg_design` table I have 2 font IDs exist.

```
$get_domain = mysqli_query( $mysqli, "SELECT edg.*, ed.domain_name, egf.* 
  FROM eg_design AS edg 
    LEFT JOIN eg_domains AS ed ON edg.domain_id = ed.domain_id 
    LEFT JOIN eg_fonts AS egf ON egf.font_id = edg.design_font AND egf.font_id = edg.domain_font 
  WHERE edg.domain_id = '$domain_id' ");
```

but I think for this line

```
egf.font_id = edg.design_font AND egf.font_id = edg.domain_font
```

The above query is not working.

I mean I can get all data but could not get the **font_name** column value. It's return only **design_font** column value not the **domain_font** column value.

Could you help me to fix it?

**Here is the fiddle:** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mNscdKDNohpT3xidp3C9Mw/0

Comment: And "not working" meaning what? Do yo get an error? Different rows than expected? No rows at all?

Comment: `egf.font_id = edg.design_font` ID is int and design_font is varchar .You should add `design_font_id`

Comment: @CyrilleConMorales I think its not a problem.

Comment: maybe we could ask if `design_font` value stored is string ? so it will not work if `23 = Serif`?

Comment: Typically it *is*  a problem when you try to compare numeric and varchar columns. But you should also add some example data. And ideally link to some dbfiddle illustrating your problem

Comment: I understand what you are talking about, I will update that column type or use the design_font_id instead later.

Comment: @derpirscher I am trying to give it now.

Comment: I have updated my question with the fiddle link: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mNscdKDNohpT3xidp3C9Mw/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you just need to left join the same table `eg_fonts` twice.

See [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mNscdKDNohpT3xidp3C9Mw/3) . You can try the query below:

```
$get_domain = mysqli_query( $mysqli, "SELECT edg.*, ed.domain_name, egf.font_name AS design_font_name , egf2.font_name AS domain_font_name
  FROM eg_design AS edg 
    LEFT JOIN eg_domains AS ed ON edg.domain_id = ed.domain_id 
    LEFT JOIN eg_fonts AS egf ON egf.font_id = edg.design_font 
    LEFT JOIN eg_fonts AS egf2 ON egf2.font_id = edg.domain_font 
  WHERE edg.domain_id = '$domain_id' ");
```

Change this:

```
LEFT JOIN eg_fonts AS egf ON egf.font_id = edg.design_font AND egf.font_id = edg.domain_font
```

To this:

```
LEFT JOIN eg_fonts AS egf ON egf.font_id = edg.design_font 
LEFT JOIN eg_fonts AS egf2 ON egf2.font_id = edg.domain_font
```

Comment: Thank You. I got an error: Undefined index: font_name

Answer (score 1):

See updated answer

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mNscdKDNohpT3xidp3C9Mw/5

```
SELECT edg.*, ed.domain_name, egf.font_name
FROM eg_design edg 
LEFT JOIN eg_domains ed ON edg.domain_id = ed.domain_id 
LEFT JOIN eg_fonts egf ON egf.font_title = edg.design_font 
WHERE edg.domain_id = 1
```

Comment: Can you tell me why you add this?

Comment: Is there any way to modify my current query?

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mNscdKDNohpT3xidp3C9Mw/2 here is another fiddle but only `eg_font` and `eg_design` since `domain` table doesnt have relational value to others

Comment: IF you want to join tables make sure that you have a `foreign key` in other tables

Comment: Thank you for your effort but it's not what I want. Maybe I am unable to explain the issues.

Comment: I updated my answer sorry i just missundertood recently what you want to achieve

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. but see an error: Undefined index: font_name

Comment: Sorry jsut delete `AS design_font_name` jsut check again the fiddle